# CSS auto horizontal margin with a bottom margin

Tags: css, margin

I have a div with a `margin: 0 auto;` and that part works great. I also want to give this div a bottom margin of 80px. I've tried `margin: 0 auto 80px;` and that work fine in webkit browsers, but not in FF. Anyone know how to achieve this for all browsers?

Comment: I should point out, in Firefox this was applying both a top and bottom margin of 80px.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you said (0 auto 80px) should work, regardless of browser unless too old. I've done it many times myself without error. I think something else is going on here, I know it sounds silly but maybe some other selector you're not aware of? this happens a lot more than one would guess.

Comment: Not silly at all, I have to be missing something. I pushed the code up to http://photoramblr.com/ ... I'd appreciate someone else's eyes on it.

Comment: You are referring to the main_wrapper btw right? This is what I'm seeing right now and everything seems fine? http://dl.dropbox.com/u/20343583/ss21.png

Comment: Yea, that's the right div. But check out the top (https://skitch.com/abeni735/g366g/photoramblr-a-photo-community). Is it not pushing the main_wrapper down for you?

Comment: OK so, you have come across the strangest bug I have ever seen. That iframe tag is your problem. Remove position absolute from it and everything goes back to normal. But I have literally not a single idea how the hell that iframe style can effect another divs formatting.

Comment: Wow, I have no idea how you figured that out or why it's happening. This is gonna be a tricky one to fix, but at least I know know where the problem lies. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: Actually I still don't think that's even the problem; if I remove the iframe entirely everything remains unaffected...

Comment: hmmmm, ok I think the problem may be about the clears. can you try the following please:
1.Remove float:left from #main.
2.Move #sidebar above the #main in the html and turn its float:right.
3.Remove the clear right before the #footer.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6839/discussion-between-tony-beninate-and-ege)

Answer (score 4):

This should do it

```
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 80px !important;
```

Comment: Yea, that should do it. For some reason it's not :/ I think my problem must be elsewhere. I'll keep digging around.

Comment: This is so bazaar; when I shut off `margin-bottom: 80px !important` in FF inspector it removes both the bottom AND pseudo-top margin it's applying.

Answer (score 2):

Why you dont realize a div with margin: 0 auto and inside this div another div with margin-bottom: 80px;?

Comment: Haha, I can't believe it, but this also reacts the same way in Firefox! I'll keep trying to get to the bottom of this :/